# How to remove initial string preceding an object

Tags: javascript, angular

I am getting a response in this format:

```
javax.xml.rpc.ServiceException: [{"ReturnCode":0,"counter":"\\\\sap\\CTI \\CTIConnection"},{"ReturnCode":101,"ErrStr":"\\\\10.77.44.101\\CTI Manager\\CTIConnectionActive;","counter":"\\\\10.77.44.10\\CTI Manager\\CTIConnectionActive"}]
```

Now the issue is coming from `javax.xml.rpc.ServiceException:` preceeding the object. I want to show an error message after checking the `ReturnCode`, but currently the only way it works is by splitting the `javax.xml.rpc.ServiceException:` part. The below code works:

```
 let errorObj = JSON.parse(errRes.error.split(': ')[1]);
let filteredError =  (errorObj.filter(val => {  
              if(val.ReturnCode !== 0) {    
                return val.ErrStr   
              } 
            }));    
           this.errorArr = filteredError.map(a => a.ErrStr);    
           let errServer = this.errorArr.map((err) => { 
            return err.split('\\')[2];  
           }).join(' ; ')
```

But, my problem is if the object contains some other error messages, then the above code will not work as expected. So, I want an alternate way where I don't have to split the string and modify. Is there a way to check the type and then omit the string part at the beginning if it exists and then do the calculation, and if it does not exist (its a JSON object), then it will do the regular map. I am not able to figure out how to do that. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like the issue is better handled in the backend rather than the frontend. Ideally the backend should send the error message as `application/json` with only the array in it's contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a regex?

```js
const text = "your response text";
const matchJava = text.match(/java.*?: (.*)/);
const matchAnything = text.match(/^.*?:\ (.*)/);
const match = matchJava || matchAnything;
console.log(match ? match[1] : text);
```

Although ideally your backend programmer should stop returning mangled data and return proper HTTP status code + parsable response.

Perhaps try with `Accept: application/json` (or any other format you expect) if the server isn't already doing that. Otherwise you're out of luck and you need to parse.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually the issue is when I check the response in `Mozilla Firefox` , it shows as `JSON` for the same, but in `Chrome` , the `javax.xml.rpc.ServiceException:` part gets added. Any idea why that might be happening?

Comment: Perhaps due to the `User-Agent` header. Try supplying one manually through the headers: `User-Agent: value` ([examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent#examples)), for example Firefox one.

Comment: @pranami alternatively, copy-paste the complete request bodies here, or check the differences locally and if possible use the same values you use in firefox also for chrome (hardcode/override). May not be the brightest idea through, still rather contact the backend programmer and tell to fix the API.

Comment: Yeah, checked with the API programmer, they said they are sending it as JSON only, and since its showing as a JSON object in Firefox, they asked to try with it. So, I am trying to find a solution to check if it contains the string, then I will have it discard the string part and continue with my operation.

Comment: Also, I tried the answer that you posted using regex, I have a doubt in that. Will it be possible to check if its a string rather than the `java...` part that you mentioned. If in case the string doesn't contain java, again the same issue. I am new to regex, so I am not able to write the expression. Can you please help

Comment: @pranami The browser ***does not*** add the `java.whatevererror`, so it's 100% fault of the backend. The programmer either doesn't know what's happening or doesn't want to fix, especially if the browser (Chrome) is [written in non-Java language](https://github.com/chromium/chromium).

Comment: @pranami Updated is the answer for all `: ` prefixes.